# How To Add Product Option of configurable product To Wish List in magento and show selected on product page

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, wishlist, attribute-options

I want to add product option in magento wishlist.
And when we click on product it will show selected on product page.
I search extension for this but i did not not found this.
My need is to saved wish list with product option and show selected option on product page....How can this possible....or any extension for this